# Biggest random number in 1-20 range

Tags: c, random, numbers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i = 1; i <= 19; i++)
        printf("%d \n", rand() * 21 / RAND_MAX);

    return 0;
}
```

The code works. Sort of. It displays in console 20 "random" numbers between 1-20. Like 1 19 6 8 18 6 8 etc. Some numbers repeat more or less.

What i need is to display the biggest number. I am noob so keep it simple.Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about that:

```
int biggest = 0;

for(i = 1;i < 20; i++){
   int num = rand() * 21 / RAND_MAX;

   if (num > biggest){
      biggest = num;
   }

   printf("%d \n", num);
}

printf("Biggest: %d \n", biggest);
```

Comment: It displays the same string number all the time. Pretty weird.

Comment: Why is that surprising? If you pick 20 random numbers from 1 to 20, there's a good chance (about 64%) one of them will be 20. Every time that happens, it will be selected as the biggest.

Comment: One minor tweak: to get numbers between 1 and 20 you'll want `num = 1 + rand() * 20 / RAND_MAX;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int biggest = 0, num;


for(i=0; i < 20; i++)
{   
    num = 1 + rand()%20; 
    if (biggest < num)
        biggest = num;  
}       
printf("%d \n", biggest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, you can do order statistics like this with a single random number.  If `k` is the number of random values and each one is in the range `1..max_value`, then:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int seed;
    /*
     * Grab a seed value from /dev/random to avoid time dependency
     * artifacts in the first generated rand() value when running
     * this multiple times in quick succession.
     */
    FILE *fp = fopen("/dev/random", "r");
    fread((char*)(&seed),sizeof(seed),1,fp);
    fclose(fp);

    srand(seed);
    int k = 20;
    int max_value = 20;

    /* 
     * The k'th root of a single uniform has the same distribution as
     * the max of k uniforms. Then use inversion to convert to desired
     * output range.
     */
    int num = 1 + max_value * exp( log( ((double)rand()) / RAND_MAX ) / k );
    printf("%d is the max of %d samples in the range 1..%d\n", num, k, max_value);
    return 0;
}
```

has the same distribution as the max of 20 random numbers in the range 1..20, with no need to loop!  Depending on how large `k` is and how expensive your `rand()` function is, this can really pay off.